# Strutting around: What's the difference between \strut, \mathstrut and \vphantom?

Tags: boxes, strut

What's the difference between `\strut`, `\mathstrut` and `\vphantom`? When would I prefer one of them to the others, and why?

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36544/4301) provides some info.

Comment: For once `\vphantom` takes some content and produces the same vertical size, while `\strut` always inserts a font-size specific but otherwise fixed amount.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Each are defined as follows in the default document classes (`article`, `book` and `report`):

#### `\strut`

```
\def\strut{\relax\ifmmode\copy\strutbox\else\unhcopy\strutbox\fi}
```

with `\strutbox` defined as

```
\setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
  \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
        \@depth.3\baselineskip
        \@width\z@}%
```

#### `\mathstrut`

```
\def\mathstrut{\vphantom(}
```

Using `\mathstrut` would be equivalent to using `\vphantom(`, with `\strut` sets a zero-width rule (`\@width\z@`) with depth `.3\baselineskip` (`\@depth.3\baselineskip`) and height `.7\baselineskip` (`\@height.7\baselineskip`). Note that the latter is font-dependent, since it uses `\baselineskip`. That is, it is modified with font change selections using `\fontsize{..}{..}\selectfont`, including the use font switches like `\small`, `\large`, etc.

I would use `\strut` within text or math, and use `\vphantom` if there is anything else I want a specific height of without the horizontal displacement. For example, when breaking two lines of math with different heights but still wanting to use extensible delimiters `\left` and `\right`. `\mathstrut` is specific to the size of `(` and (quoting [barbarabeeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton)), "`\mathstrut` is often better in math than `\strut`. Which one is better depends on the local context."

Loading the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) redefines these boxes somewhat, although their interpretation remains the same.

Comment: You should note that `\strut` is updated by every font size changing command (`\large`, `\small` and so on). What you say about "font dependency" is not very clear, IMO.

Comment: @Werner -- `\mathstrut` is often better in math than `\strut`.  which one is better depends on the local context.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: True. I'll include your comment in my answer.

Comment: And it is worth mentioning that the height of boxes in `\fbox{\strut g}\fbox{\strut \"A}` are not equal because `\strut` does not automatically detect the highest and deepest characters in the active character set.

Comment: Why is it meaningful/interesting to specify the "depth" of the vrule?

Comment: @einpoklum: The `\strut` should cover the anticipated *height* of ascenders (like those in k, l, t, ...) but also the *depth* of descenders (like those in g, j, p, q, ...).

Comment: @Werner: Ah, that kind of depth... not depth into the page. Right.

Comment: May I ask if `\mathstrut` should give different results to `{}`? For example, I don't see differences between `A^i\mathstrut_j` and `A^i{}_j`

Comment: @vagoberto: I can't find an example of it showing any different.

Answer (score 26):

The `\strut` and `\mathstrut` commands just define a box with a zero width and a convenient fixed height and depth. The last command is for math mode.

The `\vphantom` commands lets you create a box with a zero width and the same depth and height as the material that's in the argument of the command. The `\vphantom` command is ideal for scaling left and right delimiters, as is explained in the following example, which is from *[LaTeX and Friends](http://www.springer.com/computer/media+design/book/978-3-642-23815-4)*. The example requires `amsmath`. The other commands aren't as flexible.

```
\begin{align*}
f & = g\left( 3^{3^{3}} + \text{\textrm{\ldots}}\right.\\
  & \qquad \left.+ 3\vphantom{3^{3^{3}}} \right)\,.
\end{align*}
```