# Possible package missing

Tags: macros, errors

I started using LaTeX yesterday and there's something I can't figure out:
I've noticed that I don't have some commands, for example right now I'm trying to use `\vphantom` and `\phantom`, but when I type these commands they are not recognized. I've been googling but haven't found anything useful; am I missing a package or something? I've been using TexMaker and this is the only problem I've encountered so far.
Any suggestions on what is going on will be greatly appreciated,
Cheers!

Comment: Check this out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41185/10898

Comment: `\vphantom` and `\phantom` do not depend on any packages, so they should work on any LaTeX system. Can you please add to your question a *complete* and minimal document illustrating your problem?

Comment: For some reason I tried again after restarting my computer and now it recognizes the command :O, thanks for the info anyways! really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code compiles without any packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{g\vphantom{f}}\fbox{f\vphantom{g}}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

As @GonzaloMedina says, both commands are independent of any packages.