# Not enough space in table for fractions

Tags: tables

The table that I'd like to make does not display fractions with enough space between lines. What's the reasoning for this? (Not enough rep to be able to post a picture yet unfortunately.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Care type} & $\mathbb{P}(Pat \cap H)$ & $\mathbb{P}(Pat \cap H')$ & $\mathbb{P}(Pat' \cap H)$ & $\mathbb{P}(Pat' \cap H')$\\
\midrule
Direct care  &$\displaystyle \dfrac{58}{197}$  &  $\displaystyle \dfrac{48}{197}$  & $\displaystyle \dfrac{21}{197}$* &$1-\displaystyle \dfrac{58}{197}$ \\
Housekeeping &$\displaystyle \dfrac{12}{17}$  &  $\displaystyle \dfrac{2}{17}$  & $\displaystyle \dfrac{5}{17}$* &$1-\displaystyle \dfrac{12}{17}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Probabilities of hand hygiene given direct patient contact}
\label{tab:handwash_given_pat}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Image added and MWE completed.

> [image: Table with too narrow rows]

Comment: write before the `tabular` environment `\def\arraystretch{1.5}`

Comment: This also changes the spacing in the head line.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `\def\arraystretch{2}`, which is just about acceptable. Is this the best workaround?

Comment: Two suggestions. (1) Why not write 58/197 and so on? (2) All fractions are integral multiples of 1/197, so you could write everything in multiples of 1/197l this would make it easier to compare the probabilities in the same columns.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Manually the spacing can be fixed by several methods:

- `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}`  (see Herbert's comment)
  However, this also affects the spacing of the other lines.
- Adding a vertical space in the optional argument of `\\`, e.g.:

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{...}
    ...
    ...\\[2ex]
    ...\\[1.5ex]
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  ```
- Adding an invisible rule in the line, e.g.:

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{...}
    ...
    \rule{0pt}{3.5ex}Direct care ...\\
    \rule[-2.5ex]{0pt}{7ex}Housekeeping ...\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  ```

Comment: Thank you Heiko, this is very useful! :) Somehow it seems that LaTex doesn't deal with deep table cells well. Why do you think this is?

Comment: In the tables array struts are automatically added, kind of invisible rules with `.7\baselineskip` height and `.3\baselineskip` depth.
The total amount is changed by `\arraystretch`. Package `array` allows the addition of `\extrarowheight`. The strut stuff works with
normal text, but the method is limited if large objects are used.

Comment: Thanks! The "invisible rule" trick is awesome. Exactly what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 8):

I'll add three other methods.

First, since you load `booktabs`, you can add `\addlinespace` between the second and third rows.

Second, you can use the `cellspace` package, which enables you to define *minimal* vertical spacings at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you use `siunitx`). This way, the contents is vertically centred in the cell, contrary to the use of `\arraystretch`.

Last, the `makecell` package, through its `\setcellgapes` and `\makegapedcells` commands, *adds* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of every cell. This can also be done for individual cells with the `\Gaped` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cellspace}%
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{>{$}c<{$}}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Care type} & \mathbb{P}(Pat ∩ H) & \mathbb{P}(Pat ∩ H') &  \mathbb{P}(Pat' ∩ H) & \mathbb{P}(Pat' ∩ H')  \\ \midrule
    Direct care & \dfrac{58}{197} & \dfrac{48}{197} & \dfrac{21}{197} * & 1-\dfrac{58}{197}  \\\addlinespace%
    Housekeeping & \dfrac{12}{17} & \dfrac{2}{17} &\dfrac{5}{17}* &  1- \dfrac{12}{17} \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Probabilities of hand hygiene given direct patient contact}
  \label{tab:handwash_given_pat}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{>{$}Sc<{$}}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Care type} &  \mathbb{P}(Pat ∩ H)$ & \mathbb{P}(Pat ∩ H') & \mathbb{P}(Pat' ∩ H)  &  \mathbb{P}(Pat' ∩ H') \\ \midrule
    Direct care & \dfrac{58}{197} & \dfrac{48}{197} & \dfrac{21}{197}* &  1-\dfrac{58}{197} \\%
    Housekeeping & \dfrac{12}{17} & \dfrac{2}{17} & \dfrac{5}{17}* &  1-\dfrac{12}{17} \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Probabilities of hand hygiene given direct patient contact}
  \label{tab:handwash_given_pat}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Care type} & mathbb{P}(Pat ∩ H) & \mathbb{P}(Pat ∩ H') & \mathbb{P}(Pat' ∩ H) & \mathbb{P}(Pat' ∩ H') \\ \midrule
    Direct care & \dfrac{58}{197} & \dfrac{48}{197} & \dfrac{21}{197}$* & 1-\dfrac{58}{197} \\%
    Housekeeping & \dfrac{12}{17} &\dfrac{2}{17} & \dfrac{5}{17}$* & 1-\dfrac{12}{17} \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Probabilities of hand hygiene given direct patient contact}
  \label{tab:handwash_given_pat}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the package [units](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/units) and then replace your `\frac{a}{b}` with `\nicefrac{a}{b}`. The numerator and denominator will be offset diagonally and they fit nicely into tables.

Comment: You should probably also mention that if one pursues this route, the numbers will be typeset in `scriptstyle` mode, with a font size that's reduced by 30 percent relative to `textstyle` mode used in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have two keys `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit` which sets the minimal space above and below the cells of the tabular. There is also a key `cell-space-limits` which is the conjunction of these keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcccc}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
\toprule
\textbf{Care type} & $\mathbb{P}(Pat \cap H)$ & $\mathbb{P}(Pat \cap H')$ & $\mathbb{P}(Pat' \cap H)$ & $\mathbb{P}(Pat' \cap H')$\\
\midrule
Direct care  &$\displaystyle \dfrac{58}{197}$  &  $\displaystyle \dfrac{48}{197}$  & $\displaystyle \dfrac{21}{197}$* &$1-\displaystyle \dfrac{58}{197}$ \\
Housekeeping &$\displaystyle \dfrac{12}{17}$  &  $\displaystyle \dfrac{2}{17}$  & $\displaystyle \dfrac{5}{17}$* &$1-\displaystyle \dfrac{12}{17}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Probabilities of hand hygiene given direct patient contact}
\label{tab:handwash_given_pat}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

For me, `$\displaystyle \dfrac{\mathstrut 58}{\mathstrut 197}$` works well in cases in which I do only have a small number of elements. For more information about **`\mathstrut`** and friends, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41185/).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    $\dfrac{100}{30}$\\
    \hline
    $\dfrac{\mathstrut 100}{30}$\\
    \hline
    $\dfrac{\mathstrut 100}{\mathstrut 30}$\\
    \hline     
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```