# Vertical Spacing for Table with Equations

Tags: tables, spacing, equations, booktabs, inline

So I have a table with equations, below. It's a bit crunched up and I want to add vertical space in the rows. I'm using `booktabs` package for heavy lifting.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
  \toprule
  Name & Function & Derivative & \\
  \midrule
  Sigmoid & $\phi(x) = \ddfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ &  $\phi'(x) = \phi(x)(1-\phi(x))$\\
  TanH    & $\phi(x) = \ddfrac{2}{1+e^{-2x}} - 1$ & $\phi'(x) = 1-\phi(x)^2$ \\
  ReLU    & $\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
                            0 & x \leq 0 \\
                            x & x > 0
                          \end{cases} $ 
                          & $\phi'(x) = \begin{cases}
                                            0 & x \leq 0 \\
                                            1 & x > 0 
                                          \end{cases} $ \\
  Leaky ReLU & $\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
                            \alpha x & x \leq 0 \\
                            x & x > 0
                          \end{cases} $ 
                          & $\phi'(x) = \begin{cases}
                                            \alpha & x \leq 0 \\
                                            1 & x > 0 
                                          \end{cases} $ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Activation functions and their derivatives.} 
\label{tab:activation-functions}
\end{table}
```

Here's the produced output.
[image: Bad table. Bad]

I tried adding: `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` before I write the table but it messes up more. Here's the result.

[image: Worse table. Worse.]

So any idea how to make it look pretty with the equations? Looking for a relatively quick solution because this is the only table I'll have with equations. But open to anything that works.

Comment: The [answers to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67047/134144)  contain a broad variety of possibilities on how to increase the height of table rows.

Comment: IMHO, the table will look much better without the vertical lines and left-aligning the formula columns. Additional space between rows can be specified with `booktabs`' `\addlinespace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use after `\\` as `\\[3ex]` as your desire spacing by changing the value of the numeral.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}{l|cc|cc|}
   \toprule
   Name & Function & Derivative & \\
   \midrule
   Sigmoid & $\phi(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ &  $\phi'(x) = \phi(x)(1-\phi(x))$\\[3ex]
   TanH    & $\phi(x) = \dfrac{2}{1+e^{-2x}} - 1$ & $\phi'(x) = 1-\phi(x)^2$ \\[3ex]
   ReLU    & $\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
                        0 & x \leq 0 \\
                        x & x > 0
                      \end{cases} $ 
                      & $\phi'(x) = \begin{cases}
                                        0 & x \leq 0 \\
                                        1 & x > 0 
                                      \end{cases} $ \\[4ex]
   Leaky ReLU & $\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
                        \alpha x & x \leq 0 \\
                        x & x > 0
                      \end{cases} $ 
                      & $\phi'(x) = \begin{cases}
                                        \alpha & x \leq 0 \\
                                        1 & x > 0 
                                      \end{cases} $ \\
   \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Activation functions and their derivatives.} 
 \label{tab:activation-functions}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's the one I'm going with so I'll accept it. @leandriis [pointed out a duplicate which also has other options.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67047/not-enough-space-in-table-for-fractions)