# Overset placement is uneven

Tags: math-mode, spacing, align

I'm using this code to show that one element of the equation is greater than zero and the second element is less than zero.

```
\begin{align}
\overset{+}{\pi_{i}} + \overset{-}{w_{g}(S)} > 0
\end{align}
```

But the alignment of the plus and minus signs are uneven. The minus sign is quite a bit higher than the plus sign. I appreciate help getting the two at the same vertical placement.

Comment: @Mico right. `\overset{+}{\vphantom{S}\pi_{i}} + \overset{-}{w_{g}(S)} > 0`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- not quite ... for the alignment to be perfect, the first element is best coded as `\overset{+}{\vphantom{(S)}\pi_{i}}` including the parentheses around the `S`.  the difference isn't great, but if you set the two of them closely side by side, with no intervening plus, it's visible.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you're absolutely right.

Comment: I suppose the first expression could be simplified further to `\overset{+}{\vphantom{(}\pi_{i}}` or -- prettier still -- `\overset{+}{\mathstrut\pi_{i}}` (because we have `\def\mathstrut{\vphantom(}`). See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41192/5001.

Comment: @barbarabeeton in that case you could do `\vphantom{(}` and save a couple of keystrokes.

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino Did I break one of the rules in the doc you link to? Or is that actually just a welcome?

Comment: It's just a welcome for new users with a guideline; you might also be interested in the new [introduction to TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most compact approach to this is to add `\mathstrut`:

```
\begin{align}
\overset{+}{\mathstrut\pi_{i}} + \overset{-}{w_{g}(S)} > 0
\end{align}
```

explanation:

- the `\overset` adjustment is based on the tallest element in the expressions, namely the parentheses around the `S`.
- `\mathstrut` is defined as `{\vphantom(}`.

a lot of comments contributed to this.  mico's the one who finally came up with `\mathstrut`.