# Moderncv how to increase spacing between \firstname and \familyname

Tags: spacing, moderncv

How could I increase the spacing between `\firstname` and `\familyname`?

I tried redefining the `\makecvtitle` command, unfortunately I did not succeed.

I would like to make the vertical space bigger as the basic setting makes the first name and family name too close together:

[image]

I am using the classic moderncvstyle.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}



\firstname{firstname\hspace{1cm}}
\familyname{familyname}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Address}
\mobile{+123~000~000~000}
\email{email}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: in your example the names are side by side not one above the other.

Comment: I wanted to increase the spacing between firstname and lastname in case they endup on separate lines either because one of them is long or by directly adding some horizontal space, in the end I solved by using name instead of firstname and lastname.

Comment: make an example that *demonstrates* the issue, not some arbitrary MWE.

Comment: please see my added answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved by using `\name` instead of `\firstname` and `\lastname` and breaking in the second argument like this:

```tex
\name{Firstname}{\\[0.5ex]Lastname}
```

Which produces the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use [`\strut`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41185) as in

```
\firstname{\strut firstname\hspace{30mm}} % \hspace{30mm} to force a line break.
\familyname{\strut familyname}
```

> For example, LaTeX and plainTeX provide the command `\strut` to
> insert a font size specific strut. In LaTeX it has a height of 70% of
> the baseline skip (the distance between the baselines of two
> consecutive lines of text) and a depth of 30% of the baseline skip. It
> ensures that two vertical stacked boxes which include such a strut
> have the same distance like two normal consecutive lines. [*(Reference)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strut_(typesetting))

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can patch the current version 2.1.0 of `moderncv` to add a new line between first and last name with for example `\\[0.3em]` like this:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{% <==============================================
  \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
  }{%
  \namestyle{\@firstname\\[0.3em] \@lastname}% <============ change 0.3em to anything you like
  }{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother
```

Then you have no problems with the automatic generated metadatas by class `moderncv` using your given firstname and lastname without disturbing formating commands ...

With the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % head 1 body 1
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{% <==============================================
  \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
  }{%
  \namestyle{\@firstname\\[0.3em] \@lastname}% <============ change 0.3em to anything you like
  }{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother

\firstname{firstname}
\familyname{familyname}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Address}
\mobile{+123~000~000~000}
\email{email}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

you get the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]