Do vertical stents exist (for math mode)?
Update: Now that I have learned the proper name for what I called "stents," I found an excellent answer to my question, Strutting around: What's the difference between \strut, \mathstrut and \vphantom?.

Original question:
I recall mention of stents available in Latex, but I am unable to find anything online.
For example, suppose I want the text under these braces to be aligned vertically:
$\underbrace{a^b_c}_{\textrm{want vertical}} = \underbrace{d}_{\text{alignment}}$

I could insert some large pipes to achieve this:
$\underbrace{\phantom{|}a^b_c}_{\textrm{want vertical}} = \underbrace{\phantom{|}d}_{\text{alignment}}$

But unfortunately those occupy horizontal space.
(This was only an example. I ask about the existence, varieties, and use of "stents". I do not seek under-brace alignment per se.)
Do vertical stents exist that do not occupy horizontal space? Or do you have a way to create such a thing?
Thank you!

you could use \vphantom which has zero width, or \strut

@DavidCarlisle Thanks! I knew I had seen something like this, I just couldn't remember the name, and the search engines were not helpful. Using either "vphantom" or "strut" as keywords is quite fruitful.

My question was whether "stents" exist (further description of variants and their properties welcome). My question is not about how to solve brace alignment per se. This addresses the variants of "stents" available and nicely answers my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41185/strutting-around-whats-the-difference-between-strut-mathstrut-and-vphantom

@Lucas -- all three, \strut, \mathstrut and \vphantom were first defined by Knuth in plain.tex.  There, \strut is defined in terms of a box with total height and depth equal to the default \baselineskip, 12pt, and zero width.  \vphantom is defined to accept a character or string, and sets the height and depth according to what's specified, with zero width.  \mathstrut is defined as \vphantom{(}.

Thanks for the information, @barbarabeeton !
